# Hawkular agent: index out of range

Tags: configuration, openshift, agent, jolokia, hawkular

I have a problem with setting up [hawkular-agent.](https://github.com/hawkular/hawkular-openshift-agent)
I have set up the agent in OpenShift pod and I get this error log when agent tries to call the jolokia endpoint of another application running in a different pod:

```
 I0130 13:07:05.161073       1 metrics_collector_manager.go:94] START collecting metrics from [https://x.x.x.x:8778/jolokia/] every [10]s
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 11 [running]:
panic(0x11c3ac0, 0xc420016060)
    /home/mazz/bin/go-install/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a1
github.com/hawkular/hawkular-openshift-agent/k8s.K8SEndpoint.GetUrl(0xc4202a9cb8, 0x7, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /home/mazz/source/go/hawkular-openshift-agent/src/github.com/hawkular/hawkular-openshift-agent/k8s/configmap_entry.go:68 +0x26b
github.com/hawkular/hawkular-openshift-agent/k8s.(*NodeEventConsumer).startCollecting(0xc42045d2c0, 0xc42016c500)
    /home/mazz/source/go/hawkular-openshift-agent/src/github.com/hawkular/hawkular-openshift-agent/k8s/node_event_consumer.go:163 +0x10c
github.com/hawkular/hawkular-openshift-agent/k8s.(*NodeEventConsumer).consumeNodeEvents(0xc42045d2c0)
    /home/mazz/source/go/hawkular-openshift-agent/src/github.com/hawkular/hawkular-openshift-agent/k8s/node_event_consumer.go:112 +0x26d
created by github.com/hawkular/hawkular-openshift-agent/k8s.(*NodeEventConsumer).Start
    /home/mazz/source/go/hawkular-openshift-agent/src/github.com/hawkular/hawkular-openshift-agent/k8s/node_event_consumer.go:82 +0x5c5
```

Maybe someone had a similar problem? The version of agent is **Hawkular OpenShift Agent: Version: 0.1.0**.

Comment: Hi, how did you install the agent? Built from source? The current release is 1.0.0.Final and it's possible that the issue is already fixed. If not, I would suggest to open an issue on github.

Comment: @Joel thanks, I have opened an issue - https://github.com/hawkular/hawkular-openshift-agent/issues/116

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded to fix the issue by using openshift-infra project instead of openshift-infra1.